# How to enter a text in 2 UITextFields in a same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

If I am going to enter text in first UITextField  that automatically should display in second UITextField. In my case I already tried with all UITextFieldDelegate methods but if I am entering a in first UITextField I am getting a alone in second UITextField, I am getting lesser then one character.

But I Need it like if I am going type ABCDEF..... IN UITextFielD 1 IN UITextField 2 also it should be print like ABCDEF.....typing should be continued text also should be continued.

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
 UITextField2.text = UITextField1.text;

UITextField.text = textField.text;
}
```

I tried like this but not worked out. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use UILabel for second one. Because It may leads to first responder issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([textField isEqual:UITextField1]){
        UITextField2.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This method expects a return value. And what if `textField` is `UITextField2`?

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry forgot to write it

Comment: See my updated comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Objects used:**

1. `UITextField *txtFFirst;`

   - changes in `txtFFirst` propagate to `txtFSecond`
2. `UITextField *txtFSecond;`

**Possible ways:**

1. `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` notification
   **or...**
2. `UIControlEventEditingChanged` control event

---

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...

    //[1] Notification Method
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(textFieldDidChangeByNotification:)
                                                 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                               object:txtFFirst];

    //OR... (uncomment the following and comment the above)

    //[2] Control Event Method
    //[txtFFirst addTarget:self
    //              action:@selector(textFieldDidChangeByControlEvent:) 
    //    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

//[1] Fires when the Notification Method is used
-(void)textFieldDidChangeByNotification:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UITextField *txtFTemp = [note object];
    [txtFSecond setText:txtFTemp.text];
}

//[2] Fires when Control Method is used
-(void)textFieldDidChangeByControlEvent:(UITextField *)sender
{
    [txtFSecond setText:sender.text];
}
```

Comment: You should clarify that only one of the two approaches should be used. This implies both are needed.

Comment: @rmaddy : ok (_but i thought my selector method names were pretty much self explanatory_)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`, I use a different technique to handle text changes in `UITextField`s. It is similar to the `textViewDidChange:` method of `UITextView`.

You add behaviour using:

```
 [textField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then in the target method :

```
- (void) textFieldDidChange {

    textField2.text = textField1.text;
}
```

That's it. The advantage here, besides avoiding observers, is that you handle text changes *after* it actually changes.

Comment: How does this avoid observers? You are still setting up a target on the text field. The solution is fine. It's just strange that you say it avoid observers when it doesn't.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but aren't `UIControlEvents` independent of `NSNotificationCenter`?

Comment: OK, I see your distinction. I was reading the word "observers" as a more general term. You specifically meant `UINotification` observers.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITextField *sameName;

@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize name,sameName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    name.delegate = self;
    sameName.delegate = self;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([textField isEqual:name]){
    sameName.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```